# Connect OnePlus One through adb keep disconnecting

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, connection-issues, lineageos, oneplus-one

I'm trying to switch my OnePlus One from CyanogenMod to LineageOS, and to do so I need to use `adb` adn `fastboot`. I use Fedora 28 as OS on my PC, with the latest Gnome as DE.

The usual "data" connection works fine, meaning that I can access my phone's internal storage and copy files from/to that memory. Trying to use `adb`, I I changed the USB mode to "charge" and enabled `adb` from the `Developers Options` menu under `Settings`.

As soon as I connect my phone to the PC, it looks like it is stuck in a loop of connecting and disconnecting the device. I don't see any prompt on my phone regarding the `adb` connection, and `dmesg` shows the following output:

```
new high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=6765, bcdDevice= 2.32
usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 3-2: Product: A0001
usb 3-2: Manufacturer: OnePlus
usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 23deaeca
usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd
usb 3-2: device firmware changed
usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 31
```

where the `device number` starts with `1` and goes up, and up, and up, until I physically disconnect the phone.

`adb start-server` (executed as `root`) shows no error whatsoever, but `adb devices` shows nothing (both as `root` and as regular user (not `sudo`)).

What's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

After a few digging, I found out that the problem was due to an old version of `abd` in the Fedora's repository. Downloadting the latest `platform-tools` from the website fixed the problem.